# Migrating to react native 0.49

Tags: android, react-native, version

Recently I tried to update react native version from 0.48.4 to 0.49.0. I have read [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases) about breaking changes.I installed react-native v0.49.0. When I am trying to run I got error like this

```
node_modules\react-native\local-cli\util\findSymlinkedModules.js:37
ignoredRoots? = [])
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at loader (\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

I tried to upgrade using `react-native-git-upgrade` and `react-native upgrade`.But getting errors like not recognized as an internal or external command.

I found one change in New features and Enhancements change log in RN 0.49.0 like this

[Refactor how symlinks are discovered in local-cli, support scoped modules](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases).

Is there anything to do with this

Comment: Is this the complete error message?

Comment: yes.It is  @VahidBoreiri

Comment: Is your `react-native-git-upgrade` in latest version?

Comment: yes .Recently installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this thing I had to use `babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` plugin.

Steps :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types
```

In `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-flow-strip-types"]
}
```

More details https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a git repo, try deleting the project folder then re-clone the repo. This worked for a friend who was having the same issue.

I found this solution here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16458

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to `"react-native": "0.54.1",` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue updating to 0.54.

The root cause here is that Node is trying to interpret JS code with Flow types (in this case, `ignoredRoots?`).

Normally Babel would have removed these types via `babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types`, as Dinesh suggested. But that transform is contained in the standard react-native Babel preset, which does a bunch of other things too.

So what you really have to do is to make sure you have that preset setup. It should be under a `devDependency` in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
```

And then configured in `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

After that's setup you still may need to reset the packager cache:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

This is what did it for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

removing `?` from `findSymlinkedModules.js` line no 37 worked for me